# How to retrieve the logged in Google account on android phones using jquery cordova?

Tags: android, jquery

I want to be able to to retrieve the logged in Google account on android phones using jquery cordova

$(function(){

```
       $('#LoginForm').submit(function(){

        var loginData = $ ("#LoginForm").serialize();
         $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "http://admin.payerszone.net/api/Login/s_dynamic",
        data: loginData,
        crossDomian: true
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.cMessage.code)
        if(data.cMessage.code == "0"){

             window.location.href = "Home.html"
            }

           else{
                window.location.href = "Payment.html"

            }
    }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);

    });


            return false;});
   })
```

Comment: You mean after logging in to the app? Or you mean the account synced in the phone?  If you mean the later, I don't think you can since you can have more than one. You need to do the oAuth process

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I go about the oAuth process?

Comment: how do I retrieve the logged in Google account on android phones using jquery cordova after logged in to the app

Answer (score 0):

You can use this cordova plugin to go through the login process:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

```
window.plugins.googleplus.login(
    {
      'scopes': '... ', // optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
      'webClientId': 'client id of the web app/server side', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
      'offline': true, // optional, but requires the webClientId - if set to true the plugin will also return a serverAuthCode, which can be used to grant offline access to a non-Google server
    },
    function (obj) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(obj)); // do something useful instead of alerting
    },
    function (msg) {
      alert('error: ' + msg);
    }
);
```

The second parameter is a a callback function when login is successfull. the user info will be passed as a parameter to the callback allong with other information :

```
obj.email          // 'eddyverbruggen@gmail.com'
 obj.userId         // user id
 obj.displayName    // 'Eddy Verbruggen'
 obj.familyName     // 'Verbruggen'
 obj.givenName      // 'Eddy'
 obj.imageUrl       // 'http://link-to-my-profilepic.google.com'
 obj.idToken        // idToken that can be exchanged to verify user identity.
 obj.serverAuthCode // Auth code that can be exchanged for an access token and refresh token for offline access
```

Do follow the installation instructions and get the clientsId from google etc.

Hope it helps